# ¿Cómo colocar 2 etiquetas de párrafo en extremos para un footer?

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer un footer como el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que he logrado es que se muestre de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué propiedades puedo darle para conseguir ese resultado?

Comment: Para publicar consultas lo mas correcto es que publiques codigo y no imagenes, para que lo tengas en cuenta

Comment: Al footer aplicale un width: 100%, display: flex y justify-content: space between, y para alinear verticalmente align-items: center;

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la propiedad float entonces

```html
<p class="copyright">
Primer parrafo
</p>

<p class="companyname">
Nombre de la compania
</p>
```

Y aplicas un float a la izquierda y el otro de la derecha, tambien puedes usar flex y usar space between, pero float te quedaria asi

```css
.copyright {
  float: left;
}

.companyname {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo también tengo una manera de diseñar el footer. Lo de *@AugustoM* está muy bien, pero hay que llevar en cuenta que en el footer puede estar varias etiquetas para varios contenidos.

Preparé esté ejemplo para varios contenidos, o solamente para dos `p`.

Éste ejemplo es simplemente para los dos `p` centrado en el `footer`:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 1000px; /* solo demo*/
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background-color: whitesmoke
}

footer {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #333132;
 /*height: 18px;*/
 padding: .50rem 1rem;
}

footer p {
 color: #BBBBBB;
 align-self: center;
 font-family: "Palanquin Dark";
 font-size: 1rem;
 margin: 0 .50rem;
 background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<html>

 <body>
  
  <footer>
  
<p>©2022 Elemento 1</p>
<p>Elemento 2</p>
   
  </footer>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

Este otro ejemplo sería en caso de que haya varios elementos en el footer, y lo cual yo recomiendo que se use esta forma de diseño o estructura de los contenidos.

En el `footer` hay dos contenidos: `.copiright` y `img`. Estos dos elementos se puede poner en el lado que quieras: y no necesariamente con la imagen.

Si se elimina la imagen, el elemento `.copiright` se puede acomodar en el lado que guste:

```
margin: auto; /* centrado */
margin-left: 0; /* a la izquierda */
margin-right: 0; /* a la derecha */
```

Ahora lo importante de la pregunta: **alinear paralelamente los dos `p`**. Para esto, los `p` deben estar en un contenedor padre, lo cual es `.copiright`.   Éste contenedor padre debe ser `display: flex` para poder acomodar los hijos (`p`) a gusto, en este caso sin esfuerzo, con el padre con flex.

Sin encerrar los párrafos en un contenedor, sería difícil acomodar otros contenidos en el footer.

Los colores son para diferenciar, y los padding para estilizar.
El resto del código es necesario para estea demo, y para lograr el resultado.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 1000px; /* solo demo*/
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background-color: whitesmoke
}

footer {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #333132;
 height: ;
 padding: .50rem 1rem;
}

footer .copiright {
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding: .50rem;
 max-width: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-left: 0;
 background-color: lightgreen;
}

footer .copiright p {
 color: #BBBBBB;
 align-self: center;
 font-family: "Palanquin Dark";
 font-size: 1rem;
 margin: 0 .50rem;
 background-color: grey
}

footer img {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-right: 0;
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

 <footer>
   
   <div class="copiright">
<p>©2022 Elemento 1</p>
<p>Elemento 2</p>
   </div>
   
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
   
  </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Recuerda aceptar a la pregunta que te resultó útil con el ✓ para cerrar tu pregunta y no quede pendiente, y para que esto sirva a otros que busquen lo mismo.